# Grails - MongoDB - IndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm trying to learn MongoDB, but get into trouble with using embedded domain. My app has a Question, which can contains 0-many Options:

```
class Question {

    ObjectId id
    String text

    List<Option> optionList = []
    static embedded = ['optionList']
}

class Option {
    ObjectId id

    String text
    static belongsTo = [question: Question]
}
```

Now when I want to make a request to save a question with 2 options like this:

```
void testSave() {
    QuestionController questionController = new QuestionController()
    questionController.request.parameters =
        [
                "text": "test question",
                "optionList[0].text": "a",
                "optionList[1].text": "b"
        ]
    questionController.save()
}
```

this throws an exception:

```
Invalid property 'optionList[0]' of bean class [groovy.lojzatran.anketa.Question]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'optionList[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'optionList[0]' of bean class [groovy.lojzatran.anketa.Question]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'optionList[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

When I change the relationship to one-to-many with static hasMany, it works well.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this line:

```
List<Option> optionList = []
```

with

```
List<Option> optionList =  new org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList<Option>(Option)
```